# Functions (specifically text functions) within a countif function

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, countif

Is there any way to nest text operators within a countif?

I want to check if the first 4 characters of a file are in the form `A**`.

```
=Countif(Left(A1,4),"A??.") doesn't work, but I can put in a 

=Left(a1,4)
```

column and then do

```
=Countif(B1,"A??.") no problem.
```

Any way around this?  Normally I would just use if, but it doesn't accept wildcards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, you mean left, not len. No those don't work together, you need a workaround like

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A1:A10,4)="text"))
```

If you need to use wildcards, you'll need something like this -

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("a***",(LEFT(A1:A10,4)))))
```

Comment: I did mean left not len.  I also meant to include the wildcard example in my question.  Long day at work I guess.  Thanks for your psychic answer though, I'll try it now

Comment: =ISNUMBER(SEARCH("A??.",(LEFT(C18,4))))

Works great for what I want it for thanks :)

I wasn't using countif over a range, simply using it because it accepts wildcards and IF doesn't.  ISNUMBER(SEARCH makes perfect sense though for a "does this contain".  Thanks :)